# Find live variable definitions out of a basic block in llvm

Tags: c++, llvm

I need to find the variable definitions that are live out of basic block while writing an llvm pass.
Will getting the Instruction List using getInstList() help?
If yes, how do i find out which instruction is a variable definition and whats the variable. 
can somebdy plz help?